Could not launch https://www.google.com/maps?
Hello everybody
I just want to display in Google my origin coordinates and my destination coordinates in my application
this my class where , i implementing my method
class MapUtils {
  MapUtils._();
  static void lauchMapFromSourceToDestination(
      sourceLat, sourceLng, destinationLat, destinationLng) async {
    String mapOptions = [
      'saddr=$sourceLat,$sourceLng',
      'daddr=$destinationLat,$destinationLng',
      'dir_action=navigate'
    ].join('&');
    final mapUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps?$mapOptions';
    if (await canLaunch(mapUrl)) {
      await launch(mapUrl);
    } else {
      throw "Could not launch $mapUrl";
    }
  }}

when i call  it
onTap: () {
   MapUtils.lauchMapFromSourceToDestination(
   position!.latitude, position!.longitude, ifoodLat, ifoodLng);
 },

this is an expetion
Could not launch https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=-11.5926663,27.5143076&daddr=-11.6161328,27.4741627&dir_action=navigate
However, this same link functions with Google, when I launch it in the browser without going through the application
Please can  you help me

i finaly  fix it,

i added  in manifest  this  line :  <queries>           <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />         <intent>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>             <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />             <data android:scheme="https" />         </intent>     </queries>

and  change : `  String mapUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps?$mapOptions';
if (await canLaunch(mapUrl) != null) {
  await launch(mapUrl);
} else {
  throw "Could not launch $mapUrl";
}`

